# CloudBees Jenkins job unable to resolve dependencies from within my private CloudBees Maven repos

Tags: maven, cloudbees

i've got a build problem on CloudBees that i hope someone will be able to offer some suggestions on resolving.

i've got two projects:

- "common" --> a Maven project composed of three modules (models, utilities, etc)
- "service" --> a Play Framework application that depends on the aforementioned "common" project

i've configured the Jenkins job for building "common" so as to deploy to my private release repository, and i can see it does as much:

```
...
Deploying the main artifact models-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Downloading: dav:https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/models-0.0.1-20140329.091117-1.jar 
Uploaded: https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/models-0.0.1-20140329.091117-1.jar (12 KB at 246.0 KB/sec) 
Uploading: https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/models-0.0.1-20140329.091117-1.pom 
Uploaded: https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/models-0.0.1-20140329.091117-1.pom (428 B at 11.3 KB/sec) 
Downloading: https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/maven-metadata.xml 
Uploading: https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
Uploaded: https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (772 B at 19.8 KB/sec) 
Uploading: https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/maven-metadata.xml 
Uploaded: https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/maven-metadata.xml (282 B at 8.1 KB/sec)
...
```

i've configured my Play application's build.sbt file with details and credentials to read from this repository as such:

```
...
credentials += Credentials("CloudBees private Maven repos", "repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com", "username", "password")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/", 
  "CloudBees private snapshot repo" at "https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/",
  "CloudBees private release repo" at "https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/"
)
...
```

however, when i run the build job for my "service" project the dependencies cannot be found:

```
...
[warn]  module not found: com.myDomain#models;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/jenkins/.ivy2/local/com.myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/models-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/models-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/models-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== CloudBees private snapshot repo: tried
[warn]   https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/models-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== CloudBees private release repo: tried
[warn]   https://repository-myDomain.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/myDomain/models/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/models-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
...
```

i've mounted my CloudBees WebDAV snapshot and release repos, and i can see my "common" modules there... albeit suffixed with timestamp or build info.

can anyone spot something i've either overlooked?  or perhaps my understanding of this setup is inaccurate?  any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the Credentials constructor should be the realm sent in the basic auth by the server. You can also provide the credentials as [explained here](http://ricardozuasti.com/2012/using-an-authenticated-maven-repo-in-play-2-0/).

In my case, the real was `clipnow repository` and I had to add the following lines to `build.sbt` (Play Framework 2.3)

```
credentials += Credentials("clipnow repository", "repository-clipnow.forge.cloudbees.com", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD")

resolvers += "clipnow repository" at "https://repository-clipnow.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/"
```